# Inserção de dados criptografados e relacionados no banco de dados Laravel 7

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent

Salve, preciso de ajuda. Estou desenvolvendo um sistema que possui uma tabela de usuários e uma tabela de matrículas. Os dados das matrículas são relacionados à partir do CPF cadastrado na tabela Usuários. O problema é que agora preciso criptografar os dados das tabelas, criei seeds de usuário e matrícula, a de usuário é criada com a criptografia normalmente, mas a de matrícula apresenta erro que creio eu seja por que não consegue fazer o relacionamento com a tabela usuários.

Seed de usuários:

```
namespace Database\Seeders;

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;
use App\Models\Usuarios;

class UsuarioSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        Usuarios::create([
            'nome' => Crypt::encryptString('Teste 2'), 
            'cpf' => Crypt::encryptString('000000'),
            'email' => Crypt::encryptString('teste2@adm.com'),
            'telefone' => '000000', 
            'endereco' => 'nao tem', 
            'numero' => '50', 
            'complemento' => 'nao', 
            'bairro' => 'nao tem', 
            'cidade' => 'nao tem', 
            'estado' => 'nao tem', 
            'cep' => '00000000', 
            'celular' => '000000000000', 
            'password' => '$2y$10$kOAYngEkkn30WFwtePAX1ODrNNXtuCA0AKt9yhJSnZYFcqIVoj5LK', 
            'email_verified_at' => NULL, 
            'remember_token' => 'fpgOcf1SR5BLtb2GNEVigbCD2Zp7qrWMIDmwq7Qylp0vLRB4Oo7CiUG6LH46' 
        ]);

        Usuarios::create([
            'nome' => Crypt::encryptString('Teste 3'), 
            'cpf' => Crypt::encryptString('00000000'),
            'email' => Crypt::encryptString('teste3@adm.com'),
            'telefone' => '000000000', 
            'endereco' => 'nao tem', 
            'numero' => '90', 
            'complemento' => NULL, 
            'bairro' => 'nao tem', 
            'cidade' => 'nao tem', 
            'estado' => 'AC', 
            'cep' => '0000000000', 
            'celular' => NULL, 
            'password' => '$2y$10$kOAYngEkkn30WFwtePAX1ODrNNXtuCA0AKt9yhJSnZYFcqIVoj5LK', 
            'email_verified_at' => NULL, 
            'remember_token' => NULL 
        ]);
    }
}
```

Seed de matrículas:

```
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;
use App\Models\Matriculas;

class MatriculasSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        Matriculas::create([
            'matricula' => 100005,
            'nivel_acesso' => 1,
            'jornada' => 40,
            'bloqueado' => 0,
            'aprovado' => 1,
            'cpf' => Crypt::encryptString('000000'),
            'data_admissao' => '1999-11-09', 
            'cargo' => 'Administrador'
        ]);

        Matriculas::create([
            'matricula' => 100006,
            'nivel_acesso' => 1,
            'jornada' => 44,
            'bloqueado' => 0,
            'aprovado' => 1,
            'cpf' => Crypt::encryptString('000000'),
            'data_admissao' => '2003-06-06',  
            'cargo' => 'Administrador'
        ]);

        Matriculas::create([
            'matricula' => 100007,
            'nivel_acesso' => 1,
            'jornada' => 35,
            'bloqueado' => 0,
            'aprovado' => 1,
            'cpf' => Crypt::encryptString('00000000'),
            'data_admissao' => '2002-11-11',
            'cargo' => 'Administrador'
        ]);
    }
}
```

Um disclaimer é que as matrículas ficam em uma tabela separada pois um CPF pode ter mais de uma matrícula

Comment: Não entendi porque fazer isso???

Comment: Você diz a criptografia? Se sim são ordens

Comment: Você tem que pegar o mesmo dado da relação para incluir na outra tabela! é isso que você tem que fazer!

Comment: O que precisa ser feito eu sei, o problema é como, se cada vez que eu chamo essa função de criptografia os dados saem de maneira diferente, mesmo sendo textos iguais

Comment: se não sabe muito bem porque é só criar uma variavel no escopo da função e utilizar nas duas gravações!, entendeu? se faz um run() e coloca sequencia o que precisa! simples assim resolve e é ideal essa forma

Comment: Agora eu entendi, valeu mesmo